# Convert SQL query to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel I have a complex query which is a combination of sub-queries and joins. But not sure how can I convert raw query to Laravel query format. Here is how my query looks like.

I am facing problem mostly dealing with `AS` as this is not a function available in query builder I am trying to sort out the `CASE` as well, but `u1` and `u2` looks undefined to it.

```
select  `ep`.`id`, `ep`.`title`, `ep`.`slug`, `ep`.`status`, `ep`.`active`,`ep`.`visitor_id`,`ep`.`type`, `friends`.`customername`, `ep`.`created_at`, epblock.reference_id  from enr_posts as ep

JOIN (SELECT  
        (CASE WHEN u2.id = 3
              THEN u1.name
              ELSE u2.name
             END ) as customername,
        (CASE WHEN u2.id = 3
              THEN u1.id
              ELSE u2.id
             END ) as customer_id,
        fr.status
        FROM enr_friend_requests fr
        JOIN enr_customers u1 ON fr.sent_by=u1.id
        JOIN enr_customers u2 ON fr.received_by=u2.id

        where (fr.sent_by=3 or fr.received_by=3) AND fr.status="accepted") as friends 
ON ep.visitor_id=friends.customer_id
LEFT JOIN enr_post_customer_block as epblock
ON `ep`.`id` = epblock.reference_id AND epblock.customer_id=3

WHERE
    `ep`.`active`=1 AND
    `ep`.`status`=1 AND
    epblock.reference_id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    `ep`.`id` DESC
```

Is there any generator tool online as well? Because few tools I have looked into but they are not working for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a website that might be worked at complex SQL to Query Builder [SQL TO LARAVEL BUILDER](https://sql-to-laravel-builder.herokuapp.com/), that website was created by the [sql-to-laravel-builder](https://github.com/rexshijaku/sql-to-laravel-builder) repository.

As your complex query, it might convert as.

```
DB::table('enr_posts as ep')
->select('`ep`.`id`','`ep`.`title`','`ep`.`slug`','`ep`.`status`','`ep`.`active`','`ep`.`visitor_id`','`ep`.`type`','`friends`.`customername`','`ep`.`created_at`','epblock.reference_id')
->join('(SELECT  
        (CASE WHEN u2.id = 3
              THEN u1.name
              ELSE u2.name
             END ) as customername,
        (CASE WHEN u2.id = 3
              THEN u1.id
              ELSE u2.id
             END ) as customer_id,
        fr.status
        FROM enr_friend_requests fr
        JOIN enr_customers u1 ON fr.sent_by=u1.id
        JOIN enr_customers u2 ON fr.received_by=u2.id

        where (fr.sent_by=3 or fr.received_by=3) AND fr.status=\"accepted\") as friends','ep.visitor_id','=','friends.customer_id')
->leftJoin('enr_post_customer_block as epblock',function($join) {$join->on('`ep`.`id`','=','epblock.reference_id')
->where('epblock.customer_id','=',3); })
->where('`ep`.`active`','=',1)
->where('`ep`.`status`','=',1)
->whereNull('epblock.reference_id')
->orderBy('`ep`.`id`','DESC')
->get();
```

**NOTE**

But sometimes created code of Query Builder might not be the best performance, but we can modify based on that to help us improve our developing time.

so I would suggest reading [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) as well

Answer (score 1):

You can convert raw and legacy `SQL` queries into a Laravel database query builder version with **Orator**, an online tool by Maurice Calhoun. This generator could also be an excellent tool for someone learning Laravel, as it can help them translate `SQL` queries into query builder objects, as learning a new `ORM` can sometimes be a challenge for new developers.

More information here

https://laravel-news.com/convert-sql-laravel-builder-orator

Comment: Is there any link to try it online?

Comment: https://orator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ this is documentation)) on article I send you. You can see

Comment: I just tried the link you provided it looks the website is expired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184989/discussion-between-alex-malikov-and-user3201500).